# angular-rangeslider to use decimal, float values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

using Daniel Crisp's angular range slider http://danielcrisp.github.io/angular-rangeslider/. .  would like use floating values from min: 0 - max: 1

step of 0.1 (0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,...)

Comment: see what i have cooked up:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mvAv0H7tgx8ooXpakAu4?p=info

Answer (score 0):

What if you do a  math `cur / 100`  while min should be 0 and max 100?

Answer (score 0):

got it.  secret was in the filter:

```
app.filter('hourMinFilter', function () {
   return function (value) {
      if (value === 120) return 'All'
      var h = parseInt(value / 100);// changed this
      var m = parseInt(value % 100);// changed this
      m = '0.' + m; // added this
      var hStr = (h > 0) ? h + 'dollars'  : ''; // changed this
      var mStr = (m > 0) ? m + 'cents' : ''; // changed this
     var glue = (hStr && mStr) ? ' ' : '';
     return hStr + glue + mStr;
   };
});
```

worked turned into dollars and cents